# How to make weekly newsletter FILTERED (e.g. C++ only) and otherwise customizable?

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

I see the link:

> Get the weekly newsletter! In it, you'll get:
>   * The week's top questions and answers
>   * Important community announcements
>   * Questions that need answers

When I click it, it doesn't let me choose the tags/filters. I only want C, C++, valgrind, and some other tags (I don't want Java, Python, etc.).

How to subscribe for FILTERED weekly newsletter?

And how to make it not WEEKLY but bi-weekly or monthly?

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/filters/new ? You can fiter on tags, site, but the max periodicity is 1 day as far as I know